# Make position: absolute div the same width as the parent div

Tags: html, css

I have the following set up:

```css
.nav-menu-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.nav-option-container {
  width: 25%;
}

.dd-parent {
  background-color: red;
}

.nav-option-dd-container {
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  position: absolute;
}

.dd-parent:hover .nav-option-dd-container {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-menu-container">
  <div class="nav-option-container">
    a
  </div>
  <div class="nav-option-container dd-parent">
    b
    <div class="nav-option-dd-container">
      1
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I get the `nav-option-dd-container` element to be the same width as the `nav-option-container dd-parent` parent div?

I can't use `position: relative;` as that will cause my outer-most `nav-menu-container` div to expand when the hover effect shows the dropdown div, as shown below:

```css
.nav-menu-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.nav-option-container {
  width: 25%;
}

.dd-parent {
  background-color: red;
}

.nav-option-dd-container {
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  position: relative;
}

.dd-parent:hover .nav-option-dd-container {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-menu-container">
  <div class="nav-option-container">
    a
  </div>
  <div class="nav-option-container dd-parent">
    b
    <div class="nav-option-dd-container">
      1
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've also seen recommendations of setting `top`, `left`, `right`, and `bottom` to 0, but with `position: absolute;`, that results in using the root element and ends up covering the entire page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `position: relative` on `.nav-option-container`, so that when setting `left: 0; right: 0;` in the inner child, it will refer to the bounds of its parent:

```css
.nav-option-container {
  /* Add this */
  position: relative;
}

.nav-option-dd-container {
  /* And add these two lines */
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

See proof-of-concept example:

```css
.nav-menu-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.nav-option-container {
  width: 25%;
  
  /* Add this */
  position: relative;
}

.dd-parent {
  background-color: red;
}

.nav-option-dd-container {
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  position: absolute;
  
  /* And add these two lines */
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.dd-parent:hover .nav-option-dd-container {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-menu-container">
  <div class="nav-option-container">
    a
  </div>
  <div class="nav-option-container dd-parent">
    b
    <div class="nav-option-dd-container">
      1
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `position: relative` creates a new stacking context